# Validate number field with int values in Symfony

Tags: symfony

Im tryint to validate a field that should contain only an int value (1, 2, 3....), not decimals.

For that I've set in my form this code:

```
->add('page', 'number', ['data'=>1])
```

In my validation.yml I have configured this:

```
page:
  - Type:
      type: digit
```

I tried with digit, int, integer and so on, but none of them allowed me to introduce a natural number and pass the validation.

Answer (score 2):

Use http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/integer.html  and http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Range.html. Set `min` for range to 1 and `precision` to 0 for integer validator.